# Interrupt error in Intel 30386 that get pushed to stack description

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, interrupt-handling, osdev

I'm working on `interrupt`, and I need to handle failure or error during `interrupt`

I searched on Google and I found that `x86` architecture pushed  a value into the `stack` if an error happen.

I want to handle this type of error in my code but I didn't find a description ( `structer`)  on 32 bit value that get pushed into the `stack`  by the `Intel 30386`  if an error happen during interrupt.

Comment: Have you consulted the system programming guide, section _6.13 ERROR CODE_? Note that is not directly related to errors during interrupts.

Comment: i tried to look there but not include

Comment: You seem to be talking about error codes, but they don't get pushed on the stuck when an error happens during an interrupt.

Comment: @RossRidge no they get pushed look to the photo in my answer is from the manual

Comment: @robert No, error codes get "pushed" during the normal processing of certain CPU exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Frame after Exception or Interrupt ( help ilustrate the idea of error in interrupt )
[image]

and this is a segment selector (  is a 16-bit data structure) [image]

i have provided this photo just for you to understand what i'm talking about but i guess u don't need them too much right

and this is the structured you looking for with a description of each one

```
Bit 0: External event {

    0: Internal or software event triggered the error.
    1: External or hardware event triggered the error.
}
Bit 1: description location {
    0: Index portion of error code refers to descriptor in GDT or current LDT.
    1: Index portion of error code refers to gate descriptor in IDT.
}
Bit 2: GDT/LDT. Only use if the descriptor location is 0.
{
    0: This indicates the index portion of the error code refers to a descriptor in the current GDT.
    1: This indicates the index portion of the error code refers to a segment or gate descriptor in the LDT.
}
Bits 3-15: {
    Segment selector index ( also known as descriptor table index ). This is an index into the IDT, GDT, or current LDT to the segment or gate selector bring refrenced by the error code.
    }
Bits 16-31: 
    Reserved
```

**if you want to know where i get this stuff from check out the 30386 reference manual ( very good also very old ) it's like  everything that very old is very good**

Comment: can you provide links please  to the books , thank you

Comment: Intel’s latest manuals have the same information and are available here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4